# What does a device with 2FXS & 2 FXO mean

Tags: voip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does a device with 4 FXS mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/439176/what-does-a-device-with-4-fxs-mean)

as title,
What does a device with 2 FXS & 2 FXO mean
is it mean that i only can connect to 2 phone?

thanks